# Would it be possible for Xbee series2 modules to establish a 3 or more nodes network consisting of Coordinator, Router and End point? if so how?

Tags: xbee

I've established unicast communication between coordinator and router. But when i do the same to two Routers, they don't communicate. I have to send a sensor reading from a node to another node and then finally to the coordinator. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

All ZigBee networks require a single coordinator.  You can have multiple nodes on the network, and you can send messages directly between nodes.  If necessary, the ZigBee network will route the message through multiple nodes to reach the target device.

The "end device" node type is special, in that it only communicates with its "parent" node which will be the coordinator or a single router on the network.  The end device can "sleep" and the parent node will store any messages directed to that node while it sleeps.

Comment: My motive of setting up unicast communication is that i want to extend the range of my network i.e routers will be used as repeaters/relay to take message from one point to another , finally to the coordinator. What should i do? using XBee Series2.. does this module supports this type of communication..

Comment: You should look into the Series 1 module (802.15.4 instead of ZigBee) if you don't want the automatic mesh functionality.  But you'll need to keep routing tables on each node, to identify neighbor nodes and the relative link quality, and come up with some method to discover routes.